# google sheet - excel : cell value change but keep previous data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with the variables : one of them is  Cost : 15%
On another sheet that value is filled in and used when a price value is filled in. And then price and cost is calculated.
Over time the cost became 16%
But if i change that in the sheet with the variables, all my former data is recalculated with 16%.
I would like to have older rows to stay on 15% and the newer rows use 16%. And in the future 17 or 18 and so on.
I have tried several methodes , all soooo complicated. A simple one would be nice. Tx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution might be to use one cell for the old cost and another for the new cost, then on the formulas that need to use the new cost replace the cell reference to use the new one.

Another simple option might, before replacing the old cost by the new one, replace the formulas of the cells that need to use the old cost by the values. One way to do this is to do a copy - paste as value only.